# How can i troubleshoot a form.group and its controls

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a reusable control which is based on the mat-select control which i use to pass an observable as a data source so i have a quick way to drop it on any of my forms. All works fine except the disable part of the control, i am running into some issues.If i set the control to disabled it doesn't effect it. Below is some of the relevant code, if more is needit i will update question

On the parent form i set my control up like this
ngOnInit(){

```
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      sampleguid: [{value: '', disabled: true} , Validators.required]
  })
```

So my question is how can i check if the disabled value from the parent form makes it to the custom control ?
here is the code on my templete file

```
            <app-mat-dropdown 
                    placeholder="Email Type"
                    appearance="fill"
                    [clear]="true"
                    label="Phone Type Label"
                    [multiple]="true"
                    [disabled]="disabled"
                    [options]="emailTypeOptions$ | async" 
                    formControlName="sampleguid"
                    >
            </app-mat-dropdown>
```

my MatDropDownComponent extends my BaseControlValueAccessor

```
import {ControlValueAccessor} from '@angular/forms';

export class BaseControlValueAccessor<T> implements ControlValueAccessor {
    public _disabled = false;
    set disabled(isDisabled: boolean) {
        this._disabled = isDisabled;
    }
    /**
     * Call when value has changed programmatically
     */
    public value: T;

    public onChange(newVal: T) {
    }

    public onTouched(_?: any) {
    }

    /**
     * Model -> View changes
     */
    public writeValue(obj: T): void {
        this.value = obj;
    }

    public registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.onChange = fn;
    }

    public registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this.onTouched = fn;
    }

    public setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
        this.disabled = isDisabled;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a control with the formcontrolname set to "sampleguid" as defined by your form builder? If so, it would be helpful to see. If not, that might be why it's not working.

Comment: yes i do, i have a few test controls and i just copied a snippet, i fixed it in the sample